# How to do a "kill_proc()" in Linux Kernel 2.6.31.5

Tags: linux-device-driver

Trying this free forum for developers. I am migrating a serial driver to kernel 2.6.31.5. I have used various books and articles to solve problems going from 2.4

Now I have a couple of kill_proc that is not supported anymore in kernel 2.6.31.5

What would be the fastest way to migrate this into the kernel 2.6.31.5 way of killing a thread. In the books they say use kill() but it does not seem to be so in 2.6.31.5. Using send_signal would be a good way, but how do I do this? There must be a task_struct or something, I wich I could just provide my PID and SIGTERM and go ahaed and kill my thread, but it seems more complicated, having to set a struct with parameters I do not know of.

If anyone have a real example, or a link to a place with up to date info on kernel 2.6.31 I would be very thankful. Siply put, I need to kill my thread, and this is not suppose to be hard. ;)

This is my code now:

kill_proc(ex_pid, SIGTERM, 1);

/Jörgen

Answer (score 0):

For use with kthreads, there is now `kthread_stop` that the caller (e.g. the module's exit function) can invoke. The kthread itself has to check using `kthread_should_stop`. Examples of that are readily available in the kernel source tree.